# Implementing Monads in Java 8

Tags: java, generics, java-8, functional-programming, monads

I am trying to implement a Monad interface in Java 8 following [this article](https://dzone.com/articles/functor-and-monad-examples-in-plain-java) however I've got the following compiling errors

---

2 errors found:

- > File:FunctorsMonads.java  [line: 36]
  >
  > Error: FOptional is not abstract and does not override abstract method flatMap(java.util.function.Function>) in Monad
- > File:FunctorsMonads.java  [line: 50]
  >
  > Error: name clash: flatMap(java.util.function.Function>) in FOptional and flatMap(java.util.function.Function) in Monad have the same erasure, yet neither overrides the other

---

The `Functor` interface works just fine. Any help is much appreciated.

Here is the code:

```
import java.util.function.Function;

public class FunctorsMonads {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(tryParse("47"));
    System.out.println(tryParse("a"));

    FOptional<String> str = FOptional.of("47");
    System.out.println(str);
    FOptional<FOptional<Integer>> num = str.map(FunctorsMonads::tryParse);
    System.out.println(num);
    FOptional<Integer> num2 = str.flatMap(FunctorsMonads::tryParse);
    System.out.println(num2);
  }

  static FOptional<Integer> tryParse(String s){
    try {
      final int i = Integer.parseInt(s);
      return FOptional.of(i);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
      return FOptional.empty();
    }
  }
}

interface Functor<T, F extends Functor<?, ?>> {
  <R> F map(Function<T, R> f);
}

interface Monad<T, M extends Monad<?, ?>> extends Functor<T, M> {
  M flatMap(Function<T, M> f);
}

//class FOptional<T> implements Functor<T, FOptional<?>>
class FOptional<T> implements Monad<T, FOptional<?>> {
  private final T valueOrNull;

  private FOptional(T valueOrNull) {
    this.valueOrNull = valueOrNull;
  }

  public <R> FOptional<R> map(Function<T, R> f) {
    if (valueOrNull == null)
      return empty();
    else
      return of(f.apply(valueOrNull));
  }

  public <R> FOptional<R> flatMap(Function<T, FOptional<R>> f) {
    if (valueOrNull == null)
      return empty();
    else
      return f.apply(valueOrNull);
  }

  public static <T> FOptional<T> of(T a) {
    return new FOptional<T>(a);
  }

  public static <T> FOptional<T> empty() {
    return new FOptional<T>(null);
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return getClass().getName() + "<" + valueOrNull + ">";
  }
}
```

**Edit:**
I have added the following lines in the main method as a litmus test of the implementation's correctness:
`FOptional<Integer> num2 = str.flatMap(FunctorsMonads::tryParse);
 System.out.println(num2);`

Comment: Cheers @Nikolas for improving my original formatting and making the question easier to read.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot implement a fully type-safe Monad interface in Java. The correct signature for flatmap would be something like `<R> M<R> flatMap(Function<T, M<R>> f)`, but this is not expressible in Java. This `M<R>` expression is called a [higher-kinded type](http://dev.stephendiehl.com/fun/001_basics.html#higher-kinded-types).

Answer (score 1):

The implemented method `FOptional::flatMap` doesn't match the definition in the interface `Monad`.

All you need is to amend the interface `Monad` itself:

```
interface Monad<T, M extends Monad<?, ?>> extends Functor<T, M> {

    <R> M flatMap(Function<T, FOptional<R>> f);
}
```

Moreover, as far as I understand from the functionality, both interfaces shall be designed with the same spirit. Compare the new interface with the `Functor` interface:

```
interface Functor<T, F extends Functor<?, ?>> {

    <R> F map(Function<T, R> f);
}
```

Both of them define methods that return the new generic type: `Monad` with `M` and `Functor` with `F` and use a newly introduced generic type `R`.

Comment: Just that `<R> M flatMap(Function<T, FOptional<R>> f);` brings in `FOptional` within the interface `Monad`'s contracts which thereafter is *implemented by FOptional*. Shouldn't such method reside with implementations instead of interfaces?

Comment: Your answer seems to be the only possible way of making this code to compile. This shows me that @MikeFHay 's answer is the right one for the time being.